# Ruby on Rails f.submit button isn't doing anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following the tutorial [here](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i1:-form-based-workflow) and when I try to click the create article button in my web browser literally nothing happens, neither in the web browser nor the server console. The webpage renders correctly, it's just the button that isn't working. According to the tutorial I should be getting an error if the function 'create' wasn't defined in the ArticlesController class. Here is the template code:

```
<h1>Create a New Article</h1
<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>
  <ul>
  <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
    <li><%= error %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

ArticlesController

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

end
```

Comment: Ensure that you've typed `<%= f.submit %>` and not `<% f.submit %>`

Comment: yeah I copy and pasted it straight from the text file, which was copied and pasted from the tutorial site. I see the button on the webpage and when i click it, it depresses, but nothing else happens

Comment: Confirming: clicking on submit doesn't change anything in the server window i.e. no request is sent?

Comment: Nope, nothing happens in the server window.

Comment: Is `@article` `nil`? Check this by putting the following in your view somewhere, just to get an output. `<%= @article.nil? %>`

Comment: it says false. heres the ArticlesController code

Comment: Open the JavaScript console in your browser and see if any errors appear on clicking the submit button.

Comment: It just says this:
reflow: 0.54ms
reflow: 0.32ms

Comment: just tiny mistake.. u have not closed h1 tag "</h1>"

Comment: Please post your the terminal output after clicking th submit button.

Comment: oh man I feel stupid. thank you leo and everyone that helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tiny mistake, you forgot to close h1 tag `</h1>`

Answer (score 2):

try add create action and private action, for example:

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)
  @article.save
end


private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body)
  end
```